# doctrine select object without fetching all columns

Tags: doctrine-orm

i have a simple function

```
function getitembyid($id)
{
    $item = $em->find('models\Item', $id);
    return $item;
}
```

i use this function alot in my application, i am also using it with for example:

```
$item = getitembyid($id);
$item->setName($name);
$em->flush();
```

the problem now has come, that one column in the item table contains large amount of text data, which makes this query sometimes -Very slow-. (tested in normal sql, selecting without that 1 column is fast, else slow)

is there a way to change my simple function, to avoid selecting that column and without ruining the functionality of my application (updating the rows must work without touching that big column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial object approach.  Try:

```
$item = $em->createQuery("select partial i.{id,name} from models\Item i")
           ->getResult();
```

More about partial objects: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

Comment: i have tried this and i have 2 problems: first: i can not select relation to another object and second, it keeps saying: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException', i have ofcourse added a "from models\Item i where id = ".$id

Comment: editted.  You'll need to var_dump $item and debug some if that doesn't solve it.  You also might need to use getSingleResult() instead.